# Scala for web apps

Tags: scala, web-applications, web

I'm getting into **Scala**, I find the object-oriented & functional paradigm combination really interesting.

So, I've read some tutorials about basic Scala, but now I want to get deeper into Scala as for web applications.
Anyone have tutorials, links, blogs or any kind of useful information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

definitely checkout [play](http://scala.playframework.org/). its syntax is pretty sleek, has dynamic loading of classes (no restart of JVM when you make changes) and the APIs are pretty well thought.

Answer (score 4):

Try Lift: http://liftweb.net/getting_started

Answer (score 4):

I also recommend having a look at Lift since it uses Scala's strength very well. For example there's the embedded [SiteMap DSL](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/SiteMap) for structuring your site and an [actor-based Comet implementation](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Comet_Support).

In this [Interview with David Pollak](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/liftweb) he explains his reasons to start this project and (in short) Lift's benefits compared to Rails, Wicket, the Smalltalk web framework Seaside and Struts.

There are several Books about it ([Lift in Action](http://www.manning.com/perrett/), [The Definitive Guide to Lift: A Scala-based Web Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224215)), including two beeing available for free ([Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/) by David Pollak, [Exploring Lift](http://exploring.liftweb.net/) including a very interesting [chapter about Lift's internals](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-9.html#toc-Chapter-9)).

When you are from a MVC background, you should read why Lift uses a different ["View First" architecture](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/View_First) for web apps. But there's a [MVC Helper](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/MVC_(if_you_really_want_it)), too. See also [chapter 13 in Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-13.html#toc-Chapter-13) about that.

For a short look at different interesting code snippets I recommend the [Seven Things Demo Application](http://seventhings.liftweb.net/), but there also is [another offical demo](http://demo.liftweb.net/).

When you read some example view code you will probably encounter tags like `<lift:surround with="default" at="content">`. You would have to import the xml namespace to pass (x)html validators with such tags. Since this is not very designer-friendly a newer way to embed lift semantics in views is using the class attribute of a regular html element: `<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">`

Comment: I actually got kinda disappointed with the web frameworks for Scala, they all are really messy, unreadable and not well documented.

Comment: IMO especially Exploring Lift is an example for good documentation. But of course not in the meaning of API documentation... And about readability: I don't want to start the discussion if functional programming, embedded DSLs, infix notation, ... make code more or less readable. Both can be the case and it depends on the reader, too. But yes, I often was confused when I read Lift code first, too.

Comment: confused? I was lost. It was a big change, to come from something so beautiful, readable (and so well documented) as `Django`.

Comment: Ok, I don't know Django -- maybe I should have a look ;)